# React: InputMask. Почему в input не получается указать номер?

Tags: reactjs, inputmask

Установил **react-input-mask**. Маска для телефона работает, но в input не отображается, то что я набираю. В чем может бить проблема?

```
<InputMask mask="+38 (___)-___-___" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}>
   {() => <input
      type="tel"
      className={`${styles.form__input} ${isValueInput ? styles.error : ''}`}
      placeholder="Укажите номер телефона"
      ref={inputRef}
    />}
</InputMask>
```

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что `input` не получает данные `props.value` и у него не срабатывает событие `onChange`

Comment: Возможно. Есть варианты как исправить?